# Angular file manager issue

Tags: angular, typescript

i trying to make file manager from this tutorial: [FANCY TUTORIAL](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-file-explorer-component/#conclucion) In one of points implementation looks like this (in tutorial):

```
  public fileElements: Observable<MpFileElement[]>;
  currentRoot: MpFileElement;
  currentPath: string;
  canNavigateUp = false;
```

I checked a github of this project tutorial, and in mine app it looks same as tutorial. Sadly, mine version don't work. I have errors:

> Property 'fileElements' has no initializer and is not definitely
>   assigned in the constructor.ts(2564) Property 'currentRoot' has no
>   initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
>   Property 'currentPath' has no initializer and is not definitely
>   assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

What i can do in that situation?

## Clue 1

After i add ! to, for example, `currentRoot!: MpFileElement;` - problems changed to:

> src/app/main/main.component.ts:153:29 - error TS2345: Argument of type
>   'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. 
>   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>
> 153     this.fileService.update(event.element.id, { parent:
>   event.moveTo.id })

Comment: Please, more details of the problem.
Put here the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the attribute as a *string | undefined*, the method also needs to be changed.

Example:

```
currentRoot?: MpFileElement; // same currentRoot: MpFileElement | undefined

anyMethod(currentRoot?: MpFileElement) // same anyMethod(currentRoot: MpFileElement | undefined)
```

This is a union types ([here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)).
Pipe (|) is used to define several types, for example:

```
update(id: number | string)
```

When id can be **number or string**.

But if you use the exclamation (!) Operator, this is not necessary.
This is because it does not change the type of the attribute.